# Return value from temporary express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing an app that needs to authenticate externally with a service. To do this, I'm using `express` to listen to the redirect and get the data I need. However, I would like to return that data to the main scope. Here's what I have so far:

```
const authorize = () => {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('<script>window.close()</script>')
        return req.query.code;
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('listening');
    });
}

const code = authorize();
```

`req.query.code` is the data I need, and I would like to return it from `authorize()`. Instead I get `undefined`. What is the best practice to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question looks thought out, it's a minimal example, etc. You can see he's tried his best

Comment: Yeah, I explained it as well as I could. If there's anything I should add, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by returning a `Promise`.

```
const authorize = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.status(200).send('<script>window.close()</script>')
            resolve(req.query.code);
        });

        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('listening');
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: My bad. That's unrelated to the fix. I'll edit it out.